# How would I verify that a REST API call is compressing the response using Paw?

Tags: rest, paw-app

I have a REST API that I'm trying to get working with GZIP compression. I'm testing the API using Paw. My response is application/json. Three Paw-specific questions:

1. Once I get this working on the server, is there anything I need to do to configure Paw to accept a GZIP'd response?
2. Will Paw automatically un-compress for me?
3. How can I verify that the response was compressed from the server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes paw does support compressed responses:

To ensure your server returns a compressed respons ensure that
'gzip' if the first option for the `Accept-Encoding` header.

[image: Screen shot of headers]

Paw will automatically uncompress responses, to verify that the response is compress check the responses headers.

[image]

Comment: Will it also show the actual and compressed sizes @Matthaus Woolard?